# WCF Binding Filter Option

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, servicecontract, operationcontract

Is it possible that we can expose few methods `(OperationContract)` of one contract `ServiceContract)` to one `WCF` binding and rest methods `(OperationContract)` of same contract `(ServiceContract)` to other binding ?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

No. When you host your service you are free to define one or more endpoints for the service's operations in the configuration of the service. However, each of these operations will be exposed on all the defined endpoints. (The exception to this is that certain transport bindings do not support certain types of operations).

It sounds as if you should split your operation contracts into separate service contracts and then host two services.